# Динамическая генерация linq выражений

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity

Иногда, при работе с БД, необходимо генерировать sql запросы, в завмсимости от того что выбрал брокер. При  использовании SqlCommand это делается просто, конструируем строки и готово. А есть ли такая же возможность при использовании LINQ to Entities?

Comment: нельзя просто так взять и погуглить [ответ](http://www.google.com.ua/search?q=dynamic+linq) самостоятельно

Comment: @Spectre, гуглил. Но так и не смог реализовать. Может подскажите примером?

Comment: я так понимаю вам надо использовать, допустим, разные методы сортировки для выборки? так? тогда можно подставлять разные делегаты в `.OrderBy`, которые можно хранить в словаре и обойтись без [DLINQ](http://www.google.com.ua/search?q=DLINQ)

Comment: Интересна именно динамическая генерация выражения

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В принципе - да, можно, через дерево лямбда-выражений. Ещё у Entity Framework есть объектная модель запроса [`ObjectQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectquery.aspx). Полагаю, с ней будет попроще.